# Mixing LEFT JOIN results MySQL Doctrine

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine, left-join

I have a doctrine based application where I want to select rows from two separate tables and order them by creation date. I'm (sort of) accomplishing it this way right now:

```
$query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
  ->from('Embed', 'e')
  ->select("e")
  ->leftJoin("User", "u", "WITH", "e.uid=u.id")
  ->leftJoin("Product", "p", "WITH", "e.pid=p.id")
  ->where("u.image > 0 OR p.image > 0")
  ->addOrderBy("u.timeCreated + p.timeCreated", "DESC")
  ->setMaxResults(28)
  ->getQuery();
```

I would like for product and user data to be mixed, ordered by creation date, but the ordering is incorrect. I've also tried using two addOrderBy statements, which orders users and products correctly but puts all the users first in the results, rather than mixing them.

EDIT: Sir Rufo had the correct approach - here's the working code:

```
$query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
  ->from('Embed', 'e')
  ->select("e")
  ->leftJoin("User", "u", "WITH", "e.uid=u.id")
  ->leftJoin("Product", "p", "WITH", "e.pid=p.id")
  ->addSelect('COALESCE( u.timeCreated, p.timeCreated ) as timeCreated')
  ->where("u.image > 0 OR p.image > 0")
  ->orderBy("timeCreated", "DESC")
  ->setMaxResults(28)
  ->getQuery();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try this

```
$query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
  ->from('Embed', 'e')
  ->select("e")
  ->leftJoin("User", "u", "WITH", "e.uid=u.id")
  ->leftJoin("Product", "p", "WITH", "e.pid=p.id")
  ->where("u.image > 0 OR p.image > 0")
  ->addOrderBy("COALESCE( u.timeCreated, p.timeCreated )", "DESC")
  ->setMaxResults(28)
  ->getQuery();
```

Comment: With doctrine's queryBuilder that throws an exception, but I'll try to find a workaround incorporating COALESCE without using the QB.

Comment: IMHO u.timeCreated or p.timeCreated one of them will always be NULL. Adding both will result NULL. Maybe IFNULL should work instead of COALESCE

Comment: Yup that's right. I think COALESCE/IFNULL is the correct approach...now to implement in doctrine...

Comment: Got it, COALESCE was the hot ticket. I'll post the correct code in the original question. Thanks Rufo.